# trafodion can't connect to hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

**>>initialize trafodion;**
*** ERROR[1398] Error 706 occured while accessing the hbase subsystem. Fix that error and make sure hbase is up and running. Error Details:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
org.trafodion.sql.HBaseClient.(HBaseClient.java:102)

--SQL operation failed with error

i'm sure the hbase is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my previous answer was deleted when I asked for more trouble-shooting information. Try again.
I think you need to run trafodion_install to install the trafodion correctly, make sure hbase jar are in CLASSPATH after installation.
thanks,
Ming